# Chrome fails to make top element invisible and bottom element visible when doing 3d rotation (firefox works)

Tags: css, 3d

Check below snippet (in Chrome, it is working in Firefox) and see that after rotation result should be green, but is actually blue.

```css
.wrapper {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
backface-visibility: visible; /* this is needed */
animation:rotate 2s ease 0s 1 normal both running;
}
.green {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: green;
backface-visibility: visible;
transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.blue{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: blue;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
@keyframes rotate{
from{transform:rotateX(0deg)}
to{transform:rotateX(-180deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

How to fix this? I tried using `z-index` but cannot manipulate `z-index` of child nodes inside wrapper's animation (which is what is controllable). Else staticaly setting `z-index` is of no use.

The above is part of a CSS transition lib of mine (live demo [here](https://foo123.github.io/examples/imagik/)) and the transition is to start with original image , rotate and then show final image (like flipping a card which has one image on one side and second image on other side). But in chrome it fails, however I set this up to either show original image or show final image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transform-style: preserve-3d;`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_transform-style.asp) to the `class = wrapper`
Also remove `overflow:hidden` from `.wrapper` if exists, as it seems to have issues with 3d content.

```css
.wrapper {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
backface-visibility: visible; /* this is needed */
animation:rotate 2s ease 0s 1 normal both running;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.green {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: green;
backface-visibility: visible;
transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.blue{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: blue;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
@keyframes rotate{
from{transform:rotateX(0deg)}
to{transform:rotateX(-180deg)}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup you missed the 3D effect   ; )

Comment: Hmm, the issue still persists in chrome, even after adding `preserve-3d` in wrapper element.

Comment: Do you think transform-origin plays some role, as it has `transform-origin: bottom`? it also has a `z-index`. Of course this is a scaled-down version of the effect.

Comment: @NikosM. As on `edge` it is running as you wanted and also as `edge` is copy of `chrome` then it should be run on that too .

Comment: @NikosM.  `transform-origin` will only tell from where to rotate(in your case) either from center or according to other defined values(bottom, left,......)

Comment: Yes the toy example runs on chrome too, but the full effect still fails on chrome! :(. In any case this is accepted

Comment: @NikosM. what do you mean by full effect, in what contrast are you saying that

Comment: The full effect of the transition lib, this is only a toy example to showcase the problem. The toy example indeed runs on chrome now, but the full effect (after making the changes) still does not work as expected. Will try to figure out the new reason.

Comment: Yup , you can look out for some reason and try to give a read to : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin . For transform-origin better understanding

Comment: Found it!! `.wrapper` had `overflow:hidden`, using `overflow:visible` solved the issue (along with `preserve-3d`).  Live demo of the lib is [here](https://foo123.github.io/examples/imagik/)